# Linked list outputting different values to cout

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a linked list container for my homework. Using Qt 4.7 and gcc 4.4, I've found some problems in the code that I guess they are related to memory management or garbage collection.

After using the `<<` operator to display the list, all data of list is changed. for example, after construction and setting a list like `l`,

```
std::cout<<l<<std::endl;
std::cout<<l<<std::endl;
```

prints:

```
Data = [-10, 3, 2, 8, 1, -1, -2, ] // this is correct
Data = [0, 149560240, 149560192, 149558336, 149560256, 149558320, 149560208, ]
```

My linked list is:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST1_H_
#define LINKEDLIST1_H_

#include <iostream>

template<class T> class LinkedList1;
template<class T> class Node;

template<class T>
class Node
{
   friend class LinkedList1<T> ;
public:
   Node(const T& value) :
         Data(value), Next(NULL)
   {
   }
   Node() :
         Next(NULL)
   {
   }
   T Data;
   Node* Next;
};

template<class T>
class LinkedList1
{
public:
   LinkedList1() :
         size(-1), first(NULL)
   {
   }
   ~LinkedList1()
   {
      Node<T>* i = this->first;
      Node<T>* j = this->first;
      while(j!=NULL)
      {
         j=i->Next;
         delete i;
         i=j;
      }
   }
   // Operations on LinkedList
   Node<T>* First()
   {
      return first;
   }

   int Size()
   {
      return size + 1;
   }

   int Count()
   {
      int size = 0;
      Node<T>* current = this->firstFirst();
      while(current != NULL)
      {
         size++;
         current = current->Next;
      }
      this->size = size;
      return this->Size();
   }

   bool IsEmpty()
   {
      return this->Size() == 0;
   }

   void Prepend(Node<T>* value) //O(1)
   {
      value->Next = this->first;
      this->first = value;
      this->size++;
   }
   void Prepend(const T& value) //O(1)
   {
      Node<T>* item = new Node<T>(value);
      item->Next = this->first;
      this->first = item;
      this->size++;
   }
   void Append(Node<T>* value)
   {
      if(this->IsEmpty())
      {
         this->first = value;
         this->size++;
      }
      else
      {
         Node<T>* current = this->First();
         while(current->Next != NULL)
            current = current->Next;
         current->Next = value;
         value->Next = NULL;
         this->size++;
      }
   }
   void Append(const T& value)
   {
      Node<T>* temp= new Node<T>(value);
      this->Append(temp);
   }
   void Insert(Node<T>* location, Node<T>* value) //O(n)
   {
      Node<T>* current = this->first;
      Node<T>* before = current;
      while(current != NULL)
      {
         before = current;
         current = current->Next;
         if(current == location)
         {
            before->Next = value;
            value->Next = current;
            this->size++;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   void Insert(Node<T>* location, const T& value)
   {
      Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(value);
      this->Insert(location,temp);
   }

   Node<T>* Pop()
   {
      if(this->IsEmpty())
         return NULL;
      else
      {
         Node<T>* current = this->first;
         Node<T>* before = current;
         while(current->Next != NULL)
         {
            before = current;
            current = current->Next;
            before->Next = current;
         }
         before->Next = NULL;
         this->size--;
         return current;
      }
   }
   Node<T>* PopF()
   {
      if(!this->IsEmpty())
      {
         Node<T>* head = this->first;
         this->first = this->first->Next;
         this->size--;
         return head;
      }
      else
         return NULL;
   }
   Node<T>* Remove(Node<T>* location)
   {
      // validating by IsEmpty is not necessary for this operation,
      // while statement's condition guarantees validation
      Node<T>* current = this->first;
      Node<T>* before = current;
      while(current != NULL)
      {
         before = current;
         current = current->Next;
         before->Next = current;
         if(current == location)
         {
            before->Next = current->Next;
            current->Next=NULL;
            return current;
         }
      }
      return NULL; // Not found...
   }
   void Inverse()
   {
      if(this->IsEmpty())
         return;
      else
      {
         Node<T>* r = NULL;
         Node<T>* q = this->first;
         Node<T>* p = this->first;
         while(q != NULL)
         {
            p = p->Next;
            q->Next = r;
            r = q;
            q = p;
         }
         this->first = r;
      }
   }
   // Ordered insertion. implement this: foreach i,j in this; if i=vale: i+=vale, break; else if i<=value<=j: this.insert(j,value),break
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LinkedList1 item)
   {
      out<<"Data = [";
      Node<T>* current = item.first;
      while(current != NULL)
      {
         out << current->Data << ", ";
         current = current->Next;
      }
      out<<"]";
      return out;
   }

   void HelperOutput(std::ostream& out, const LinkedList1 item) const
   {
      out<<item;
   }

   Node<T>* operator[](const int& index)
   {
      int i=0;
      Node<T>* current = this->first;
      while(i<=index && current!=NULL)
      {
         if(i=index)
            return current;
         else
         {
            i++;
            current=current->Next;
         }
      }
   }
public:
   int size;
   Node<T>* first;

};

#endif /* LINKEDLIST1_H_ */

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LinkedList1 item)
   {
      out<<"Data = [";
      Node<T>* current = item.first;
      while(current != NULL)
      {
         out << current->Data << ", ";
         current = current->Next;
      }
      out<<"]";
      return out;
   }
```

first item in output of second call is always `0`. So I Thinked I've set `first` to `NULL` in somewhere in code; but I checked out all of methods and there was nothing like that. In addition, printed value is not the pointer itself; it's pointer's `Data`. Somewhere somebody changes `Data`s of all `Node<T>*`s in my list.

Is this a memory management or garbage collection issue? if not, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post you entire linked list class?

Comment: There is no garbage collection in C++, and memory management is something you have to do on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that stands out here is that your signature is:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LinkedList1 item)
```

Instead of:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LinkedList1& item)
```

So, you are invoking a copy of your LinkedList. I suspect the issue here is that you have not correctly implemented your copy and assignment operators for LinkedList1, such that the the copy references the original content, and the destructor is making the original object into garbage.

I would recommend adding the following to your definition of LinkedList1:

```
private:
    // The following declarations disallow copy and assignment. Do not implement.
    LinkedList1(const LinkedList1&);
    LinkedList1& operator=(const LinkedList1&);
```

Adding the above will lead to linker errors for the original signature that you had. I would then recommend passing the linked list by const reference, and your problem should disappear.

As an aside, I notice that many of your functions can be made `const` but aren't. For example, you have `int Size()` instead of `int Size()const`. One should generally mark as const anything that can be so-marked. This is known as "const-correctness" and can avoid a large number of issues.

Also, minor style nitpick: you have if...else statements where one has braces and the other doesn't. I would strongly recommend that you use braces in all cases as this leads to more readable code.

Comment: Oops! I forget an &. I'll also add above methods. thnx.